# Разделить массив на несколько... (улучшить текущий код)

Tags: c#, массивы, инспекция-кода

Существует массив типа string с неизвестным размером от 10 до 5000.
Требуется перевести значения массива в строчки с добавлением "," но с учетом что в каждой строчке должно быть не больше 350 значений массива и добавить каждую строчку в новый массив.

Написал такой извращенный код, он работает, но можно же красивей и проще ?

```
string[] lines //массив от 10 до 5000 значений
string[] rez = new string[30]; //результат 

int i = 0;
int c = 0;
int b = 350; //максимум значений в строчке
int v = (int)Math.Ceiling(lines.Count() / (decimal)350);

for (int s = 0; s != (v); s++)
{
    for (i = c; i < b; i++)
    {
        rez[s] += lines[i] + ",";
    }

    if (s != v - 1)
    {
        i += 350;
        b += 350;
    }

    c += 350;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте через LINQ:

```
static class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<R> SplitIntoGroups<T, R>(
        this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int n, Func<IEnumerable<T>, R> convert)
    {
        return sequence.Select((t, idx) => new { t, group = idx / n })
                       .GroupBy(p => p.group, p => p.t)
                       .Select(convert);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        var lines = numbers.SplitIntoGroups(3, group => string.Join(",", group));
        foreach (var line in lines)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Или более прямолинейный вариант:

```
static IEnumerable<R> SplitIntoGroups<T, R>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int n, Func<IEnumerable<T>, R> convert)
{
    List<T> cache = null;
    foreach (T t in sequence)
    {
        if (cache == null)
            cache = new List<T>();
        cache.Add(t);
        if (cache.Count >= n)
        {
            yield return convert(cache);
            cache = null;
        }
    }
    if (cache != null)
        yield return convert(cache);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить такой non-generic вариант конкретно для вашей задачи:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoGroups(this IEnumerable<string> sequence,
                                               int n, string separator)
    {
        while (sequence.Any())
        {
            yield return string.Join(separator, sequence.Take(n));
            sequence = sequence.Skip(n);
        }
    }
```